# faster sorting in laravel eloquent timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my laravel project I have a table called tracker_videos which keeps track of videos seen in my site and it is rather a large table. I want to run a query to get all unique videos in a period of time ordered by updated_at descending. This is my migration:

```
class CreateTrackerVideoTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('tracker_video', function (Blueprint $table) {
            ....
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->index();
            $table->timestamp('updated_at')->index();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my query:

```
$query = TrackerVideo::select($params);
$query->selectRaw('max(updated_at)')
            ->groupBy('source_id', 'source_video_key')
            ->orderBy('max(updated_at)','desc') ;
```

I get the result however but I takes around 3 seconds for server to return the response. Is there any way in laravel to speedup my query in server?

[EDIT]

When I comment the line  `orderBy('max(updated_at)','desc')` the response will return in less than a second but when I un-comment it , it takes 3 seconds to response so i think the timestamp is the bottle neck.

table structure:

```
create table tracker_video
(
id bigint auto_increment
primary key,
watch_times int(10) unsigned default '0' not null,
viewer_client_id int(10) unsigned null,
referrer_client_id int(10) unsigned null,
source_id int(10) unsigned not null,
source_video_key varchar(255) not null,
session_uuid varchar(255) not null,
created_at timestamp default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' not null,
updated_at timestamp default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' not null,
adpack_id int(10) unsigned null
)
;
create index tracker_video_created_at_index
on tracker_video (created_at)
;


create index tracker_video_source_id_source_video_key_index
on tracker_video (source_id, source_video_key)
;
create index tracker_video_updated_at_index
on tracker_video (updated_at)
;
```

Comment: How many entries are in the table? Is `source_id` indexed?

Comment: around 800000 record. and the `source_id` and `source_video_key` are indexed together

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  Which columns define a video as being a duplicate?  Can you post your table structure?  From what I see so far this is more of a MySQL question than anything else.

Comment: added table structure in question

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?